# I have grub installed twice, what will happen if I remove the 1st install?

Tags: grub2

My hard drive:

- sda1: SUSE
- sda2: new Ubuntu, installed yesterday
- sda3: win7

When I turn on my PC it always uses the SUSE boot loader. When I format the partition with SUSE will my PC automatically start using Ubuntu's grub or will I have to install/repair something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files your current grub uses are on the SUSE partition, so if you remove that partition, grub will fail.  Rather than jump off the cliff, just run Ubuntu, and install grub from there

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

That will then have grub using files on the Ubuntu partition, and you may freely remove the SUSE partition.